# Use column from GSpreadsheet for questions in GForm?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

---

I have a Google Spreadsheet that contains (among other things) one column with questions. Now I need to create a Google Form with N questions of type `Text` for which the `Question Title` is taken from my spreadsheet (where N is the number of rows in my spreadsheet; currently ~ 100).

Is there a straight-forward way of doing that?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Create a app script in your spreadsheet like so:

```
function createForm(){
var form = FormApp.create('A New Form');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var rangeValues = sheet.getRange('A1:A20').getValues();


for (var x in rangeValues){
  form.addTextItem().setTitle(rangeValues[x]);
}

Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());

}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! In retrospect, I am a bit confused that I couldn't figure this out myself. It seems blatantly obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question that I feel isn't worth another topic. Maybe you can give me a hand? I am using `FormApp.openByUrl` when creating the form/modifying it because the URL needs to remain constant (can't just `.create()` a new one each time. But this will append all items I create to the existing form which is not what I want. So I thought I'd first delete all items from the current form before running the loop that adds the ones I want. I am using this: var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i in items) {
    form.deleteItem(i);
  }

but get an index-out-of-range type error. Any ideas?