# How to delete all items from an FormApp object?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

[I recently asked a question about how to add items to a Google Form from a Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036889/use-column-from-gspreadsheet-for-questions-in-gform). And it works great. Instead of using `FormApp.create()`, though, I'll have to use `.openByUrl()` because the ID has to stay the same. The problem is that if I run my script again, it'll open the existing form (great) and then append more items to the existing form.

This behaviour makes perfect sense but is not quite what I want. So I thought I'd just remove all existing items before I add new ones from my spreadsheet. I consulted [the Google dev site for Form Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) and feel like I should have all the pieces. I can't quite put them together, though.

I am now doing this following:

```
var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/.../edit');
var items = form.getItems();
for (var i in items) {
    form.deleteItem(i);
}
```

However, that'll give me an out of range error. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with how you're iterating over the array.

Try this:

```
var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/.../edit');
var items = form.getItems();
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  form.deleteItem(i);
}
```

Comment: This still gives me errors such as `Cannot access item at index: 18. Number of items: 18.` Something seems to go wrong with the indexing.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem.  As items are deleted, the index is changing.  My solution was to use `form.deleteItem(0)` which just deleted the first object over and over again until they were all gone (just edited @teatimer's answer to reflect that).

Answer (score 4):

```
function clearForm(){
  var items = form.getItems();
  while(items.length > 0){
    form.deleteItem(items.pop());
  }
}
```

Comment: Although simple, it's still a shame that this work-around has to be done. Should be a method of the Form Class by now.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the same problem. This one worked for me:

```
function deleteItems(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('ID');
  var items = form.getItems();
  items.forEach(function(e){form.deleteItem(e)}) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I ran into the same issue:

```
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] != null){
        form.deleteItem(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by deleting the last item and repeat it until all items are deleted. This could be done by a reverse for loop:

```
function deleteAllItems(){
  var form = FormApp.openById(/*put here your form id*/);
  var items = form.getItems();
  var end = items.length - 1;
  for(var i = end ; i >= 0; i--){
    form.deleteItem(i);
  }
}
```

Another alternative is avoid of a variable index by using `0`, so the first item will be deleted, no matter if a regular or a reverse loop is used. Note: This was already mentioned in a comment to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/.../edit');
  var items = form.getItems();
    while(items.length > 0)
    {
     form.deleteItem(items.pop());
    }
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking the length of a variable=form.getItems() in a loop, its going to through some error because the length of that is not changing and the loops end up being infinite and throughing error.
So, heres my solution to the problem:

```
 for(;form.getItems().length>0;)
 {
     form.deleteItem(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. However, I have fixed it by iterating in the reverse order.

```
var form=FormApp.openByUrl('form url here');
var Items=form.getItems();
var len=Items.length;

for (var i=Items.length-1;i>2;i--){ //Delete every item except first three items
form.deleteItem(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for looping over all form items and removing each, the most succinct being:

*With Chrome V8 runtime*

```js
form.getItems().forEach(form.deleteItem)
```

*Without Chrome V8 runtime*

```js
for each (var item in form.getItems()) {
    form.deleteItem(item);
}
```